# How to make redux action dispatched in component unmount reach the store before previous page useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 2 react components:

```
const PageA = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    doXXXX()
  }, [])

  return ....
}

const PageB = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    return () => dispatch(SomeReduxAction())
  }, [])
  return ....
}
```

When the user goes from PageA to PageB, then goes back in history to pageA from PageB. The useEffect block in Page A runs before the `SomeReduxAction` reaches the redux store which is dispatched when PageB unmounts. This causes a bug. Is there a way to get the `SomeReduxAction` to reach the redux store before PageA runs useEffect?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible for PageA to call an effect before PageB has finished unmounting. Is it possible you are having routing issues? In other words, is it possible that there is a render cycle in which PageA AND PageB are rendered concurrently?

Comment: @CHess You are right that the unMount block in PageB is reached before the useEffect block in PageA. But I think since dispatching an action is asynchronous, the unMount dispatch the action and finished before the action reaches the redux store and changes the store's state.
The bug in PageA is caused by the changed redux store state... However updating the store state in PageA also causes another bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dispatching an action is asynchronous. And it triggers when component unmount, you can't wait for it to finish on the call side.

But you can listen to state changes in the Redux Store. Use a state as the dependency of the `useEffect`, so that when the state changed, the `useEffect` will execute again. Then you can decide whether to execute the code or not like `doXXXX()` function.

E.g.

```js
const PageA = () => {
  const someReduxActionStateSlice = useSelector(state => state.someReduxActionStateSlice);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(someReduxActionStateSlice === condition) {
      doXXXX()
    }
  }, [someReduxActionStateSlice])

  return ....
}

const PageB = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    return () => dispatch(SomeReduxAction())
  }, [])
  return ...
}
```